# UITableViewCell displaying incorrect data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I am trying to output my NSMutableArray in a UITableView, the tableView is showing but it's output is incorrect data. I am expecting something like this

```
Check   10
Try     11
Test    12
```

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Check",@"Try",@"Test" ,nil];
arr2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"10",@"11",@"12", nil];
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 400, 500, 500)];
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.delegate = self;
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cells"];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cells" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 50, 50)];
[images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[cell addSubview:images];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(131, 27, 59, 21)];
label1.text = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label1];

UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(231, 27, 67, 21)];
label2.text = [arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label2];

return cell;
}
```

And it's output is

```
Check    10
Try      11
Check    10
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to set a tag to each of UILabel objects if you are going to use a custom UITableViewCell?

Comment: @ElTomato - No, that's how we did it many years ago, but that practice is now discouraged. The best practice nowadays is to use cell prototype, set the base class, and hook up outlets in IB. But you definitely shouldn't just add subviews like he has here, as when cells are reused, duplicate labels will be added. Or if he's going to create programmatically, he should check to see if cell was dequeue do and only add subviews if it's a new cell. And he'd update his properties to point to these labels, not use tags.

Comment: drbj, are you really dealing with only three cells? Your code could produce the sort of behavior you describe only if cells were scrolling out of view and other cells scrolling into view (and typically you'd only see that behavior if you had quite a few rows of data).

Comment: @Rob  I see.  Thanks.  I guess I was thinking about an old fashion where you work with UITableView and UITableViewCell without Storyboard.

Comment: No worries, it's just that a custom class' properties are a much better way to keep track of the controls than the old approach, even if you're doing everything programmatically.

Comment: @Rob nope, the cells will be dynamic. what change should i apply?

Comment: drbj, Cuong's answer is an example of how you should do this, if you're doing it programmatically. Frankly, it's even easier if you're doing this with storyboards and cell prototypes because other than some trivial code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, there's practically no code to write at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23746714/1271826.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't addSubView in cellForRowAtIndex of tableview delegate. Because it's called multiple times. In your case, custom an UITableViewCell such as:

MyTableViewCell.h :

```
@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
- (void)setImages:(UIImage *)images label1:(NSString *)label1 label2:(NSString *)label2;

@end
```

MyTableViewCell.m :

```
@interface MyTableViewCell()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *images;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label2;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    _images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 50, 50)];
    [self addSubview:_images];

    _label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(131, 27, 59, 21)];
    [self addSubview:_label1];

    _label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(231, 27, 67, 21)];
    [self addSubview:_label2];
}

- (void)setImages:(UIImage *)images label1:(NSString *)label1 label2:(NSString *)label2 {
    _images.image = images;
    _label1.text = label1;
    _label2.text = label2;
}
```

And modify your code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cells" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSString *text1 = [arr1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text2 = [arr2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell setImages:image label1:text1label2:text2];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: @interface MyTableViewCell : BaseViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> this is currently in my header

Comment: @drbj - That makes no sense. A `MyTableViewCell` should, if it's really a cell in a table, be declared like Cuong has here. Don't confuse the cell with the view controller. The only thing missing from this answer is to replace your `registerClass` code with `[self.tableView registerClass:[MyTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cells"];`.

Comment: I followed your code, and i am error at this line [cell setImages:image label1:text1label2:text2];  No visible @interface for 'UITableViewCell' declares the selector 'setImages:label1:::'

Comment: @drbj Oh sorry, i has mistake. i'll modify my answers

Comment: Fixed it now, but it is throwing exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell setImages:label1:label2:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9578d80020' in the [cell setImages:(image) label1:(text1) label2:(text2)]; that i made

Comment: Hi, please follow tutorial, this is simple and easy to understand than my answers : http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/